# Traversing a binary search tree

Tags: c++, c++11, binary-search-tree

I've implmented a basic binary search tree. Here's my node

```
 #ifndef NODE_H
    #define NODE_H

    template<typename T> class node{

        template<typename E> friend class bst;

        public:
            node():data(0), left(NULL), right(NULL){}
            node(T data):data(data),left(NULL), right(NULL){}   

        private:
            T data;
            node<T>* left;
            node<T>* right;
    };

#endif
```

And here's my bst.

```
#ifndef BST_H
#define BST_H

template<typename T> class bst{
    public:
        bst():root(NULL), nodes(0){}
        bst(node<T>* root):root(root), nodes(0){}

        void insert(node<T>* root, const T& data){

            if(root == NULL){
                node<T>* root = new node<T>();
                root->data = data;
                nodes++;
                return;
            }else if(data <= root->data) {
                insert(root->left, data);

            }else if(data >= root->data){
                insert(root->right, data);

            }
        }

        void preorder(node<T>* root){
            if(root == NULL) return;
            std::cout<< root->data<<'\n';

            preorder(root->left);
            preorder(root->right);
        }
    private:
        node<T>* root;
        int nodes;
};
#endif
```

Here's the calling function

```
int main(){

    node<int>* root = new node<int>(17);
    bst<int>* t = new bst<int>(root);


    t->insert(root,21);
    t->insert(root,12);
    t->insert(root, 9);

    t->preorder(root);

    delete t;
}
```

The output is simply 17, which is the root. I feel somehow my insert method hasn't worked right, since the preorder is a pretty standard implementation. Can somebody help me as to what is going wrong here.

Comment: `insert` doesn't actually insert. It just creates a local variable.

Comment: @0x499602D2 You are right that `insert` does NOT insert here, but should that be a local variable? because that'll stay alive even out of scope (which is a leak eventually)

Comment: Can someone please help me modify the insert logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems.

The first is that you are declaring `root` as a local variable inside `insert()` method. This name overlaps to data member root.

The second is that, as you have designed it, the root is not updated.

This code should work:

```
void insert(node<T>*& root, // <-- root as reference for updating
            const T& data){

        if(root == NULL){
            root = new node<T>(); // <-- here you update root
            root->data = data;
            nodes++;
            return;
        }else if(data <= root->data) {
            insert(root->left, data);

        }else if(data >= root->data){
            insert(root->right, data);

        }
    }
```

Of course, you could refactor and thus to get a more concise and elegant implementation. But this should produce the result that you expect

Answer (score 2):

Inside insert do not create a local variable, just use the one passe. So instead of

```
node<T>* root = new node<T>();
```

do just

```
root = new node<T>();
```

And pass root by reference. I would do it with a typedef

```
typedef node<T>* nodePtr;
void insert(nodePtr &root, const T& data){
```

but you can do it also without

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the root by refrence, and do not create a local variable shadowing it:

```
// ...
void insert(node<T>*& root, const T& data){ // passed by reference

            if(root == NULL){
                root = new node<T>();       // reference overwritten
//...
```

This gives me

```
17
12
9
21
```

as output, as expected of preorder I guess.